# angularjs, posting $scope, and select boxes

Tags: angularjs

I'm messing around with angularjs (which is awesome btw) by creating a form. I load data from json, I can successfully read the data, but I have a couple of questions in regards to the plunker I've made. (http://plnkr.co/edit/LHX40xHKmoB9onboeNrV?p=preview)

I have 2 forms on there, both half work. Before I continue, a request for the angularjs pro's out there: Overall is my plunker code style the proper angularjs way? How can I improve it? Thanks.

Anyways, the following snippet is the difference between the 2 forms:

***FORM#1:***
For the form to work, I specified '`country`' which gets it's value from `countries` in the json.

**JS**:

```
$scope.vm.country = data[0].countries[0];
```

**HTML:**

```
Country: <select ng-model="vm.country" ng-options="c.name for c in vm.countries"></select>
```

***FORM#2:***
The JSON for this is slightly different to #2. The `countries` array is called `country`. The select options expr references itself - failing. The json submitted here `on-click` has the correct value for country code/name which is what I'm after, but it also contains the `cities` array, which is not what I want.

**JS**:

```
$scope.vm.country = data[0].country[0];
```

**HTML:**

```
Country: <select ng-model="vm.country" ng-options="c.name for c in vm.country"></select>
```

I'd like to know exactly why the select boxes are behaving the way they are in form2.
As for submitting the form, it's obviously not desirable to send useless data. So how would you go about sending only the stuff you need in `$scope.vm`? For a small form, manually adding each input to a new $scope item would work fine, but for a huge form with many inputs it wouldn't be ideal.

**UPDATE**

Here's a working solution with appropriate values that are put into a separate variable (`$scope.form`). Also, `$watch` has been changed to `ng-change`. This may help others.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NDSvKS0mEF1Wgp2CBIOB?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a subtle bug. If you take a look at your json file you'll notice your "list" of countries is named country. **Change that to countries**. The reason it's failing is because you override the entire list when you set your vm.country in the controller. I've forked / update your **[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zv8loPCeAsVDJahMJKdg?p=preview)** to show a simple fix.

As far as the form data goes you'll probably want to wrap your selects in a form element and get the value(s) that way. Check out [Angularjs's Page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform) on the matter.

> Overall is my plunker code style the proper angularjs way? How can I improve it? Thanks.

It's not bad at all, given it's only a few controllers. A few things to help you out that I've found in using angular:

1) Debugging html can be annoying for cases like these. Luckily angular's "angular.element" method returns the html AS WELL AS the ability to inspect the scope of the element. Watch this [debugging tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TM6wG9UW7s) on how that works. The same concepts should apply regardless if your using firebug or chrome dev tools.

2) Think of ways you can avoid the $watch method where at all possible. The reason is that this method is called every time ANY update happens in your app even if the update is not directly related to the scope it's called on. As a suggestion you may wish to add an ng-change directive to the select statement which should only fire when the actual dom element changes, rather than having the $watch fire every $digest in the framework.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you know what is the best approach to use $watch? I didn't notice this behavior until I see your post.

Comment: In general I find you really only need to add $watch's to custom directives. Rare circumstances may permit a controller, but I think you'll find the $emit, $broadcast, and $on scope methods far more useful to communicate with.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Very interesting stuff. I didn't know $watch should be avoided! I've played around with this in plunker with the suggestions you mentioned. Here's a forked plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EyiyKB2A7zDcbGLscqaS?p=preview I've used ng-change, and the most controversial part (in my mind) is angular.copy of a couple of values. Is this best practice? thanks!

Comment: @Riffic RE: "As far as the form data goes you'll probably want to wrap your selects in a form element and get the value(s) that way."
I couldn't really understand what you meant or how i could implement the stuff from the documentation.

Comment: Was the data going to be sent to a server or submitted to another portion of the app? If it's the server simply include the action and the url like a regular html form (make sure to name your input's in the form though). If you wanted to send more than what the form values are, you would have to manually specify what you want sent just as you started to do, and send it via another http request. Make sure to select my answer if it helped.

Comment: @Riffic submitting the form the normal way would be too easy for a learning exercise :) I wanted to create a json obj to sent to mvc web api